# I want to append version number to all js files using ant build script by maintaining dir structure

Tags: javascript, file, build, ant, rename

I have multiple js files and want to append or add version number , at the time of build .
However i want to maintain dir structure as well for deployement

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: @CAustin I tried to add version number with build task in jsp from which all js are called,and appended at js call.Which worked fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<copy todir="${sourse_dir_path}/js/" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="Destination_path/js"/>
        <firstmatchmapper>
            <globmapper from="*.js" to="*-${major.minor.number}-${build.number}.js"/>
        </firstmatchmapper>
    </copy>
```